# Why is scanf results different from user input?

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

```
char* ReadNumericFormat = "%i";
int Read(void)
{
    int Storage;
    __asm
    {
        LEA    EAX, [Storage]
        PUSH   EAX
        PUSH   DWORD PTR [ReadNumericFormat]
        CALL   DWORD PTR [scanf]
        ADD    ESP, 8
        MOV    EAX, DWORD PTR [Storage]
    }     
}
```

when the user enters "023919" the procedure returns 19.
this is a feature or darkness is a standard?

Comment: You're using inline assembler to replace one line of C code?  Either this is an exercise to learn inline assembler, or you *really* need to learn something about optimization. :-)

Comment: @Paul Tomblin:I am trying to reduce code-bytes.

Comment: This is an interesting code...It kind of defeats the whole purpose of using a high-level language....

Comment: @tommieb75:the only reason for me using c++ is "it is always easier than MASM."

Comment: When posting a question about inline assembly for something you could write in C (such as calling into a C standard library function), it would make a lot more sense to try writing the  equivalent C function, and only post an "inline-assembly" question if C and inline assembly don't produce the same result.

Comment: @bk1e:1.I thought the problem is with the assembly code. 2.I just copied and pasted the code and i had no reason to change it.3.i don't have the code anymore.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262041/obj-to-cpp-converter

Comment: Too bad, because I would have challenged you to compare the "code-bytes" of this ASM versus "scanf("%i", &Storage);return Storage;".

Comment: @Paul Tomblin:i cannot challenge you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262041/obj-to-cpp-converter

Comment: "2.I just copied and pasted the code..." Well, there's your problem. :)

Comment: @bk1e:I copied the code from VS not a Website.I'm not a script kidy.

Comment: That's a lot harsher than the term I would have used, which would have been "copy and paste programmer". Anyway, since you're essentially rewriting the output of a highly optimized compiler, I hope you already took advantage of the easy ways to reduce executable size (`/Os` compiler option, UPX compression, etc.), assuming that reducing overall executable size is your goal.

Comment: **Please kindly change the title of your post according to the content of your question. That will help others to provide more answers and to gain knowledge by searching your question**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually that's because you've entered an *octal number*.

In C, numbers starting with 0 will be interpreted as octal (base-8) literals. Hence, in your input

```
023919
```

`scanf` find a leading zero without an `x` following, so assumes it's an octal number. Then it consumes `2` and `3`, until `9` which is not a valid octal digit and stop. So `scanf` now has

```
023
```

which is

```
2*8 + 3 = 19
```

So the procedure returns 19.

---

Use the format `%d` instead of `%i` to prevent this.

Comment: so it is a *forgotten* feature.because scanf should raise an error when the input-string is incorrect.

Comment: No, it's scanf acting the way it has for decades, and the way it is documented to work.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same if you used `scanf` directly (without inline assembly). "023" is the octal representation of 19, and scanf stops at the "9" in "0239" because that can't be an octal digit.