# .obj to .cpp converter?

Tags: file, visual-studio-2008, decompiling, delete-file, .obj

Is there any .obj to .cpp converter?
Is it possible to do it?
MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO auto-magically deleted my code files when pressed the F5 key.
Please help me.
I have the .obj files (VS forgot to delete them.ha ha ha).

Comment: Good time to start using Source Control Management

Comment: Seriously? The first thing VS does when you compile is save the files so the compiler can find them (because the compiler is a separate process from the IDE itself). I remember a Borland IDE back in the 90s would compile in-memory because it was faster, and when it crashed it *would* lose your source code. Anyway, check to see if it put the files somewhere other than where you're looking.

Comment: downvote?I think he was bill gates, and i have made one of their buffer overflows public.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill:what is the default directory for them?(writing them again takes less time than searching 20M MFT Entries)

Comment: lets don't talk about it anymore.it makes me feel worse.

Comment: Believe it or not, it did happen to me also! 2 source files ware just disappeared forever. not even in recycle bin. You never know how much shits can happen until it happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is impossible to decompile an .obj file back to source. [More info here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/58956).

Comment: Impossible? You've obviously never used IDA.

Comment: @Frank Krueger:IDA works good but i cannot pay for that. While(Countries::C_Iran::LastMessage::Nuclear>0.05)IAEA::GetCountryA(Countries::C_Iran)->Boycott++;

Comment: ida has a free version. not sure if it will help though... you will be rewriting the .cpp files no matter what; there is no magic bullet for this.

Comment: These days Ghidra and Cutter (Rizin or radare2) would be free-of-charge options.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [Recuva](http://www.recuva.com/)

Answer (score 2):

shut down your computer, boot from removable media, some sort of the UNIX, and run strings utility on your hard drive. It may be able to recover text off your source code.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has pointed out, this is impossible.

I would suggest that before you rebuild all those files, you take the time to look into SVN or another version control system.

Version Control allows you to save copies of your files to a safe place.  If the compiler eats your homework, you can update with the last copy you saved to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck. There is no safe way to reverse an obj file back to its cpp source.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is actually possible.  You'd be reversing the compilation process, which from my knowledge is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do that...as all the code's comments and variables are translated into a machine code, you cannot deterministically reproduce a variable name by gleaning in on assembler byte code, Consider this as an example of a mock dump of a binary image:

```
0x55 0x90 0x33 0xf0 ....
```

Now, how can you tell that's variable `foobar` that is of type `int`....

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: ooo really.most of the code was inline-assembly.how can i reverse the engine?

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier, it is impossible to get the C source code from on obj. As an alternative, you can try a file recovery utility and scan your disk for lost files. I have previously used testdisk with partial success.

Also, you really need to use some form of SCM!

Answer (score -1):

NO, it's not possible. obj files contain object code, not source code. The compilation process is typically not reversible.

PS: Visual Studio did surely *not* delete your code files when you pressed F5. They are somewhere, or you've deleted them accidentially.

Comment: when i pressed the f5 key.vs started compiling.in the middle of process.messagebox(0,"Access denied","microsoft visual studio", 48);

Comment: @Behrooz: I think that would be a symptom that some other process deleted the files and VS failed to read them and threw out an access denied message.

Answer (score -1):

.obj files are text files for a 3d model I was actually looking for something to bring them into C++ to display using OpenGL.  there are programs out there to load them into C++ I was looking for one to download when I came across this.

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obj

Comment: I am not doing graphics.I am writing in C++.I have wrote them all again.

Comment: Please delete this answer. It's wrong and completely off-topic. Yes, I know the name "object file" is also used for meshes, but *this* question was about [these object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code).